# Rails 3 :remote => true & . creating duplicated calls to create

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

After searching for a while and narrowing it down to a specific problem I've decided to finally signup and ask you good people for some help. Here goes:

**I create a form with:**

```
= form_for @note, :remote => true do |f|
```

**use .build (or .create) inside the controller:**

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.build(params[:note])
    if @note.save
      respond_with @note, :location => root_url
    end
  end
```

**and it loops through the the create block twice.**

If I use `Note.new` or remove `:remote => true` then everything works fine, but the combination of both is breaking everything. Note creation is working fine in the console and it's not throwing up any errors anywhere so I'm stuck.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: You mean browser is sending two Ajax calls to create method?

Comment: Please check the javascript console, upon remote => true is it sending two requests?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using remote true then you need to create one create.js.erb as by default it will try to render js.erb

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you create a blank object in your new action, and populate the object with parameter values before saving in your create action. Try this:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    @note = Note.new
  end

  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.new(params[:note])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.save
       format.js
      end
    end
  end

end
```